# In SQL Server how to give only "read only" permission to all DB objects?

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, readonly

I need to give read only permission to a couple of users on the database so that they can get an understanding of the schema, logic in SPs, etc. But I do not want them to modify anything. I tried assigning the db_datareader role but it doesn't allow viewing SP name or code. What is the right role-combination to do this or do I need to write a T-SQL script to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to grant the rights to view everything under the dbo schema:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON schema::dbo TO [UserName]
```

Comment: Will that allow selecting records from tables? Or did you mean a db_DataReader + this GRANT option?

Comment: If you need the users to also select data, you'll need to issue the statement I provided along with DataReader.

Comment: Also, note that my usage of GRANT VIEW DEFINITION is just one example, really.  I suggest reading up on this command in SQL Books Online for using it with a different level of scope, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to write a TSQL script to grant view on the SP's.  DB_DataReader only gives read access to the user tables; it doesn't include any other rights.  And I know of no included database role or server role that will do what you are asking.